# Swift: get the offset value from a date object

Tags: swift, date

as simple as it sounds, but it is hard to find my exact question in google. 
I'm trying to ignore the UTC printed out value. I receive multiple dates, this one here is just an example: (it could be +0900, -0200, etc...)

> "2017-05-01T12:30:00-0700"

once I apply it to a value using these lines:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
if let result = formatter.date(from: time) {print result}
```

the value of the dateTimeResult prints:

> 2017-05-01 19:30:00 UTC

Using swift date objects, how do I slice out the part "-0700", multiply the -7 or +7 (this example is negative) by minutes by seconds. I'll save that total as int in DB (I need it for categorizing the different timezones later). Then applying that total to the incoming date input using this line:

```
let output = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: totalSecs, to: result)
```

The goal is to end up with this date:

> "2017-05-01 12:30:00"

I already have a solution using string manipulation, but I don't think that is the ideal solution. If it must be done by string, how do you do it?

Comment: I am saving that part of date offset for later uses. I'll update question to make that clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want only the date and time portion ignoring always the time zone information.

In this case strip the time zone from the date string with regular expression

```
let dateString = "2017-05-01T12:30:00-0700"
let dateStringIgnoringTimeZone = dateString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[+-]\\d{4}", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
print(dateStringIgnoringTimeZone) // "2017-05-01T12:30:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStringIgnoringTimeZone)!
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should keep the date as it is and then just use DateFormatter to display the time at that timezone

```
let time = "2017-05-01T12:30:00-0700"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .iso8601)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxxx"
if let result = dateFormatter.date(from: time) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: result))  // "2017-05-01 16:30:00   (corresponding time at my location GMT-3)
    // to display it at -0700 just set the formatter timaZone
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -3600 * 7)
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: result))  // "2017-05-01 12:30:00\n"
}
```

To get the timezone offset from the string:

```
let hours = Int(time.suffix(5).prefix(3)) ?? 0
let minutes = Int(time.suffix(2)) ?? 0
let offset = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 
print(offset)   // -25200
```

Comment: the -7 hours is an example, it could be -8, +4 etc... how do you get that hour difference? String manipulation?

Comment: Don't mess with the time zone. use the current one. If you want to display the time at another location you should display the location besides it. If you need the components get the dateComponents

Comment: If you need the offset `TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()`

Comment: You are the master at this type of questions no doubt... but beside my need to display, my DB is expecting the part: -0700 or +0800 etc... (after I convert it to seconds), I need to somehow get it. TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT() shows my device location. I care about the location of the one who entered that time, that I am getting from.

Comment: I don't think you understood if you get the offset and add the seconds to the result you will get another date. I mean it won't be the same point in time anymore.

Comment: I should amend my question entirely and just ask about how to get that offset value. I confused the issue by mentioning both needs...